# In html file <% tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for ="<%= id %>"><%= label %></label>
 <div class="col-md-4" >                     
  <textarea class="form-control" id="<%= id %>" name="<%= id %>" ><%= textarea %></textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'am searching bootstrap form builder

https://github.com/IhabSoliman/Bootstrap-Form-Builder

No server-side programming language is used in form builder app and all file in html but some tags like <%= id %> I don't know what the tag is in html file

You can download builder app and then  in assets/js/templates/snippet folder all the html files included. You can look that files to see this tags.

Shortly, I want to know which language tag it is

Comment: Ruby on Rails template language?

Comment: ASP/ASP.Net is what it's used for.
`<%=` is pretty much shorthand for `Response.Write(id)`

Comment: Several languages use this syntax for template strings.

Comment: But no any asp or aspx file and tags in html file. I have no server program IIS or apache vs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using [Underscore's template compilation](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> Template functions can both interpolate variables, using <%= … %>, as well as execute arbitrary JavaScript code, with <% … %>.

Answer (score 0):

Several (javascript) templating engines like EJS use this syntax in order to output data.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case this tag is used as a placeholder in a JavaScript template. Libraries like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) use it to parse templates and display the parsed content.

I am not familliar with the above library, but in most JavaScript template engines, you would pass the template and your parameters as function arguments and you would get a string you could inject into the DOM. Underscore handles it this way:

```
   var tpl = _.template('<div class="form-group"> \
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for ="<%= id %>"><%= label %></label> \
     <div class="col-md-4" > \                    
      <textarea class="form-control" id="<%= id %>" name="<%= id %>" ><%= textarea %></textarea> \
     </div> \
    </div>');

    var result = tpl({
            id: "1",
            label: "this is a label",
            textarea: "this is the content of the text area"
    });
```

I believe Bootstrap-Form-Builder works simmilar.